# Foreach loop error Invalid argument

Tags: php, foreach

When I run the code my browser shows: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

$inputCount has a value of 9

```
$QCount = $inputCount/3;
echo $QCount;

Foreach($QCount as $value) {
    For($x=1; $x<=3; $x++) {
        echo nl2br("\n question".$count2." options: \n".$optionData[$optionsCount]."\n");
        $optionsCount+=1;
    }
    $count2+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach works only on arrays or objects. It is giving invalid argument as the value $QCount is scalar ie 3. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

> The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays. foreach works only on arrays and objects, and will issue an error when you try to use it on a variable with a different data type or an uninitialized variable.

As @Sachin Gotal rightfully stated, you are trying to loop an integer saved in $QCount.